# What is usage of Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure

Why we need Azure Mobile Service , even though we have Web API , WCF to communicate across device and across protocols. I mean is there a situation that Azure Mobile Service comes into picture and solve our problem?

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment to improve this question?, else it is very unclear why you are doing so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's how to see it: Azure Mobile Services primary target are mobile apps devs that don't have a lot of experience coding the backend part of a solution or simply want to focus on coding the app and spend less time coding the backend.